# Kusto restrict all table and function except specific table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Right now Kusto provides `restrict` statement for middle-tier application to limit access to database and database's table/function. According to docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/restrictstatement?pivots=azuredataexplorer, there is no option to exclude a specific table from `restrict` statement. Is there anyway to do this without listing all the tables/functions that my client allowed to query on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict does not support exclusion, however if you want to restrict access to a specific table you should consider enabling the [RestrictedViewAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy) policy on that table. This means that you will have to explicitly allow access to the table for a specific set of users and everyone else will not be able to access it.